# Why does display: table behave differently in Firefox and in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-tables

I'm making a layout that looks kind of like this

```
All contained withing a 'table' (display: table)
 __________________
| S| HEADER        |
| I|---------------|
| D|               |
| E| CONTENT       |
|  |_______________|
|  |FOOTER         |
--------------------
```

`SIDE` is a `table-cell` and `HEADER, CONTENT, FOOTER` are contained within another `table-cell`. `CONTENT` is a `div` that has `overflow-y` set to auto, and in Chrome, whenever the content in `CONTENT` exceeds the initial height, the scrollbar appears and the whole table isn't resized vertically, however, in Firefox, the whole table IS getting expanded vertically, which is not the behavior I expected.

My table has the `table-layout: fixed` property and `overflow: hidden`. **Is there anyway I can prevent the table from expanding vertically in Firefox?**

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a table for this. Use flexbox or grid or floates.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for the interesting question. If you include some sample code to reproduce the behaviour you're describing in your post, it would be easier for people to quickly observe what you're talking about and figure out an answer, improving your odds of getting one. Good luck. :)

Comment: Did you manage to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

mention some height

```
<td>
<div style="height:200px;
overflow:hidden;">
contents goes here
</div>
</td>
```

adjust the height, it should cut off the extra lines out from your sight